# Facebook Dynamic Product Ads + Magento 2

Tags: facebook, magento, magento2, facebook-pixel

We want to display Magento 2 products at Facebook Dynamic Product Ads.

I am a little bit confused.
Google says that 'Facebook Pixel' is a solution.
I got many free links for download facebook pixel extension.
Is my question that displays dynamic Magento products to facebook through just install 'Facebook Pixel' extension?

How can I display dynamic Magento products on facebook?

Is their any Magento 2 extension?

Comment: you are looking for this module -: https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento2-facebook-conversion-audience-tracking.html

Answer (score 1):

In order to display your Magento 2 products within your Facebook Business Manager Catalog (Dynamic Ads) or within your Facebook Store, you need to set up a feed in your Facebook Business Manager account and provide it to URL of your feed -

[image]

[image]

The feed CSV file generation itself can be done in two ways:

1. Manually, by creating the CSV feed file on your server. See a CSV sample here - https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=dpa_product_catalog_sample_feed.csv. And here is the Facebook documentation and explanation of the CSV fields - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/product-catalog/#setup-product-feed
2. Using a custom extension. One of such extensions is [Facebook Shop Integration by Mexbs](https://www.mexbs.com/facebook-shop-integration-magento2-extension). 
   It implements a cron that creates a CSV feed file on an hourly, daily or weekly base. For configurable products, the feed file builds up a special structure that allows displaying drop downs of the options in the Facebook store. It also implements quick shop functionality. That is the product is added to cart and the customer is redirected to checkout immediately after clicking the "Checkout on Website" button on Facebook.

**Disclaimer**: I am the CEO of MexBS (the company who developed the extension mentioned above)